# Can't Ping or connect to the Network on my Linux

Tags: linux, apt, repository, ping

I tried installing some days back, and my connection stopped. I closed the terminal and since then can't connect to the internet.

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

comes back with no update or errors. When I

```
ping www.google.com
```

I get:

> Name or service not known

While,

```
:~# traceroute google.com
```

came back as:

```
google.com: Name or service not known
Cannot handle "host"cmdline arg `google.com` on position 1 (argc 1)
```

I did a:

```
yum search repository
```

and got an error.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Is this for wireless? Output from "ifconfig" may be helpful.  What did you try installing?  You may be missing some information (is this a wholly new installation?)

Comment: Check the resolver configuration (/etc/resolv.conf) and see if you are able to reach an external location by it's IP address (ping 8.8.4.4)

Answer (score 1):

Check in this order (with outputs from my system, adapt the steps to your system):

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlan0 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.21
```

So my default gateway (my home router is `192.168.178.1`) on the network interface `wlan0`. Look at the network interface:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
...
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb state UP group default qlen 30
  link/ether 00:0e:2e:9d:e5:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 192.168.178.21/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global wlan0
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 fe80::20e:2eff:fe9d:e508/64 scope link 
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My network interface is up and has address IPv4 address `192.168.178.21`. Try to ping the router (use the IP of your router):

```
$ ping 192.168.178.1
PING 192.168.178.1 (192.168.178.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.178.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.901 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.178.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.20 ms
```

So that works, I can reach my router. Try to ping something on the outside, here a Google server:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=67.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=66.0 ms
```

Also works.

If any of the above steps fails, we know where to look for the problem. If they succeed, we still need to check your name resolution.

Comment: Hey dirkt, your suggestions have been helpful so far but when i pinged my IP it says "Destination Host Unreachable"

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of all steps. I'm not sure what you mean by "my IP". The IP of the router?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the `Name or service not known` error , edit your `/etc/resolv.conf` then add your DNS servers e,g:

For IPv4:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

For IPv6:

```
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844
```

Save and restart the network service :

```
systemctl restart network
```